# Limited inserts per second RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

My inserts do not exceed 25 per second on RDS. I'm using MySQL Community with db.t3.large on Amazon RDS.

In my Mysql on AWS instance its be more than 300 inserts per second. Something is weird.

Is there a limit? Some parameter that can change?

I tried `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit (1 -> 0)` and the `sync_binlog (1 -> 0)` but it didn't work.

Every help is welcome.

Comment: I benchmarked RDS twice in recent years, for two different employers. It's really terrible at write performance. Basically I wouldn't use RDS for anything more demanding than a blog or something else with very low write throughput requirements. Aurora is much better. But what I ended up recommending after comparing benchmarks was to run MySQL Server manually on storage-optimized EC2 (e.g. one of the i3 instance family) with direct-attached NVMe storage.

Comment: Is your storage type is optimized for write intensive workloads? In AWS, IOPS SSDs > gp2. If you've fine-grained access, you can also look up: batch insertions and connection pooling. As already mentioned, Aurora is better for write intensive workloads.

Comment: Hi, Aurora is more expensive. :( 
I migrated my MySQL Server on EC2 to RDS, because they tell me it was safer than the other one. I cant migrate this again now.